Azure Functions - storage connection
I have an Azure functions app which is running under a managed identity connecting to the private endpoint of a storage account in the same vnet, via an integration subnet. The function works fine if I allow all network traffic to access the storage, but when I disable public access, the function fails with the following error:

When I do an nslookup from the functionapp, it is resolving to the internal IP address but when the function app accesses the storage it comes in with an IP address that is not within my VNET range.
I have been sitting with this problem for over a week now, and I really don't know what the answer is?
Any insights would be so welcome

Ensure that the managed identity for your Azure Functions app has the appropriate role assignments to access the storage account also verify that the integration subnet is properly configured and delegated to the Azure Functions service. The subnet should be linked with the function app and have sufficient permissions to access the storage account

Thanks for the insights @alex.

Add the below settings in the Function app=>Application Settings, refer MSDOC:

WEBSITE_CONTENTOVERVNET=1
WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL=1



Check if Azure Functions app is correctly integrated with the virtual network (VNet) containing the storage account.

Make sure you have created and configured the private endpoint for the storage account and is correctly linked to the correct subnet and VNet.

The managed identity of function app should have Storage Blob Data Contributor assigned to it to access the storage account.



Enable Managed Identity in Azure function App.



Assign Storage blob data contributor role to the managed identity of the function app.



Ensure that the NSG rules (if enabled) allow traffic between the Azure Functions subnet and the storage account subnet.

Enable logging for both the Azure Functions app and the storage account and check the logs to identify any errors occurring when the function app tries to access the storage account.


I have tested the same in my environment by disabling the public access in both function app and Storage account and integrated with virtual network private endpoints.

References:

Use private endpoints to integrate Azure Functions with a virtual network.

